# CSS - img:not selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Any idea why the not selector below for the image is not working?

I want the not selector prevent the picture from having 20% width. I am trying to select the class test which my image is a part of.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRNOgx

```
<style>
img:not(.test){
    width:20%;
}
</style>
<html>
<div class="test"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pMKpE40.jpg"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector matches an `img` element so long as it is not a member of the `test` class.

You have an `<img>` and it has no `class` attribute at all.

The `<div>` is a member of `test`, the `<img>` is not.

`:not(.test) > img` would not match that `<img>`, but it might not cover all your use cases.

CSS has no way to say "Element has no ancestor which matches a selector".

Comment: Can you post an example code?

Comment: @DavidSomekh — I did! (Unless you mean an example of the thing I said was impossible, in which case: No, it is impossible).

Comment: Thx quentin, your answer helped me understand the issue.